# When you deploy contract, is it reset balance of your computed etereum address?

Tags: contract-deployment, balances

Before further situation description, sorry for my poor English skill.

I sent my ethereum to estimated(?) contract address before contract is deployed.

it will be contract address soon, but it is not contract address yet (this happened because of bridge error)

What I want to ask is that, when they(bridge owner) deploy contract

Will my Ethereum balance be maintained? (The ethereum I sent to address)

Or when you deploy contract, Ethereum balance reset?

Answer (score 0):

> Will my Ethereum balance be maintained? (The ethereum I sent to address)

Yes. The account maintains the amount of ETH independently regardless if the account has code deployed or not.